# Canvas App Export Error

Tags: permissions, error, migration, export, powerapps-canvas

I am fairly new to canvas apps and I am facing an error there.
I want to migrate Canvas apps so trying to export it. But I am running into an error :
[image]

Has any one come across this? Kindly help me if so.
Appreciate your response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you application owner? Do you have access to all connections used in app?